# Send a string from client to server, then save the file [using C]

Tags: c, client, http-post, server

I have these two C codes below consisting of a client and a server. The code is simple:
1- Server listens and waits for a connection
2- Client sends a string HTTP Post to Server
3- Server gets the request, posts back a response
4- Client receives response

But what I want is for the server to save the string to disk. For example, if Client (device) sends "Hello World", then I want to be able for the Server (PC) to save that in a text file.

Here's the server code

```
/*server code*/    
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define PORT "3434"  // the port users will be connecting to

#define BACKLOG 10     // how many pending connections queue will hold

void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
}

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(void)
{
    int sockfd, new_fd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes=1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
                sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        return 2;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

    while(1) {  // main accept() loop
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        if (new_fd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
            get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
            s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
            close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
            if (send(new_fd, "Server : I received your request \n", 23, 0) == -1)
                perror("send");
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the Client code

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf, sprintf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* read, write, close */
#include <string.h> /* memcpy, memset */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* socket, connect */
#include <netinet/in.h> /* struct sockaddr_in, struct sockaddr */
#include <netdb.h> /* struct hostent, gethostbyname */
#include <unistd.h>

void error(const char *msg) { perror(msg); exit(0); }

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    /* what and where are we going to send */
    int portno =        3434; /* 3490 or 8080 */
    char *host =        "192.168.1.65"; 
    char *message_fmt = "POST HTTP/1.0\n";

    struct hostent *server;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int sockfd, bytes, sent, received, total;
    char message[1024],response[4096];


    /* fill in the parameters */
    sprintf(message,message_fmt,argv[1],argv[2]);
    printf("Request:\n%s\n",message);

    /* create the socket */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    /* lookup the ip address */
    server = gethostbyname(host);
    printf("ip address: %s\n\n", host);
    if (server == NULL) error("ERROR, no such host");

    /* fill in the structure */
    memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);

    /* connect the socket */
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting");

    /* send the request */
   printf("Sending request\n\n");
    total = strlen(message);
    sent = 0;
    do {
        bytes = write(sockfd,message+sent,total-sent);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR writing message to socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        sent+=bytes;
    } while (sent < 0); //while (sent < total);
    printf("I am a string post \n");

    //receive the response
    printf("Receiving response \n");
    memset(response,0,sizeof(response));
    total = sizeof(response)-1;
    received = 0;
    do {
        bytes = read(sockfd,response-received,total-received);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR reading response from socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        received+=bytes;
    } while(received < 0); //while (received < total);
    printf("Response received\n");

    if (received == total)
        error("ERROR storing complete response from socket");

    /* close the socket */
    close(sockfd);

    /* process response */
    printf("\nServer Response:\n%s\n\n",response);

    return 0;
}
```

**Server stdout**

```
server: waiting for connections...    
server: got connection from 192.168.1.65
```

**Client stdout**

```
Request:
POST HTTP/1.0

ip address: 192.168.1.65

Sending request
I am a string post     

Receiving response
Response received

Server Response:
I received your request
```

Comment: Where does the server actually send `I received your request` in *any* of this code? The only send I see from the server is `"Server : OK \n"`. And regardless, writing data to a `FILE*` should be *trivial* if you authored *this*. `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fclose`, etc.

Comment: @WhozCraig ah my mistake, it was at the bottom of the server code towards the final 9 lines. It was previously set to "Server: OK" instead of "Server:  I received your request". I've edited it again now.

Comment: It *still* would not produce the posted output; rather with the code as-is-now the client would *try* to print "Server Response:\nServer : I received your". But what I said prior stands; adding a `FILE*` dump of received response buffers should be straight-forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part you didn't include in your server code:

```
3- Server gets the request, posts back a response
```

You need something like:

```
char buf[N];
ssize_t len;

len = recv(sock, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0);
if (len > 0) {
    buf[len] = '\0';
    /* save to file */
}
```

after `accept()`

Comment: I've tried the code below but it still doesn't seem to save what the client sent. What am I doing wrong?

`char buf[1000];  
 ssize_t len;  
  
  len = recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0);  
  if (len > 0) {  
       buf[len] = '\0';  
       /* save to file */  
     
        FILE *fp;  
     char str[1000];  
     //fscanf(fp," %s",str);  
        fgetc( fp );  
        fp = fopen( "file.txt" , "w" );  
        fwrite(str , 1 , sizeof(str) , fp );  
        fclose(fp);  
    
   }
`

Comment: `fgetc`?, no, use `fwrite` with your current already allocated `buf`

Comment: In other words, you don't need `str`, `fwrite(buf, 1, sizeof buf, fp)` directly

Comment: I've tried using it as you said, but still no files are being saved. Here's the sample (http://ideone.com/swIdeV), I tried putting the above code in lines 124 and tried again with line 132. Could it be I placed it in the wrong line?

Comment: I found my mistake: I was looking at the wrong socket address (sockfd instead of new_fd). Works now, thanks.